# @Service injection into aggregates?

Tags: domain-driven-design, axon

I have an `Order` aggregate with the following commands:

- `CreateOrderCommand`
- `PlaceOrderCommand`
- ... (rest redacted as they are not pertinent to the question) ...

The `PlaceOrderCommand` refers to placing the `Order` onto an external execution venue. I have captured the behaviour for placing an order onto an external execution venue within a separate (non CQRS) `@Service`. However, I am struggling (due to lack of experience with Axon) with how best to connect my `@Service` with the aggregate.

My normal way of thinking would have me:

- Inject the `@Service` into the aggregate's `@Autowired` constructor.
- When the `PlaceOrderCommand` is issued, use the service to place the order onto the relevant execution venue and once done emit an event (either `OrderPlacedSuccessfullyEvent` or `ErrorInOrderPlacementEvent`).
- Change the aggregate's state within the relevant `@EventSourcingHandler`.

My question is:

- does my description above of how to handle this particular use case with Axon make sense (in particular injecting a `@Service` into an aggregate feels a bit off to me)?
- Or is there a different best practice of how to model my scenario when using CQRS/event sourcing with Axon?
- Axon requires an empty constructor in the aggregate. How does this reconcile with having the `@Autowired` constructor?

The other thing I was potentially considering was:

- having a `PlaceOrderInstructionCommand` (instead of the simple `PlaceOrderCommand`) which emits a `ReceivedPlaceOrderInstructionEvent` that a separate event listener is listening for.
- that event listener would have the relevant `@Service` injected into it and would do the placement of the `Order`.
- then after placing the `Order` it would send a command (or should it emit an event?) to the aggregate informing it to update its state.

Could you please advise on what is best practice for modelling this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The PlaceOrderCommand refers to placing the Order onto an external execution venue.

I'm assuming that placing the Order to an external execution venue means interacting with an external system. If yes, then it is should not be part of your domain. In that case, you would need to raise an `Integration Event`.

As you mentioned, you could raise a `Command` like `ProcessOrder` from your Domain. Within that `Command`, you can update your `Domain` (eg, set the `OrderStatus` to `Processing`) and raise an integration event like `OrderArrived` which is then handled by a separate process.

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/domain-events-design-implementation#domain-events-versus-integration-events):

> The purpose of integration events is to propagate committed transactions and updates to additional subsystems, whether they are other microservices, Bounded Contexts or even external applications.
>
> Integration events must be based on asynchronous communication between multiple microservices (other Bounded Contexts) or even external systems/applications.

You would handle that integration event as a separate process (or worker) outside of your `Domain`. This is where your`@Service` would be injected. Once, the order is processed successfully you can then broadcast integration event called `OrderPlaced`.

Now, any subscriber which has anything to do with placing the order would subscribe to the event. In your case, your `Domain` is interested in updating the state once the order is placed. Hence, you would would `Subscribe` to `OrderPlaced` event within your `Domain` to update the status of the `Order`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you this has made things clearer. Regarding the separate process/worker that would sit outside the domain: do you have any links on how best to model that with regards to the Axon framework?

Comment: HI @vab2048, I do not have experience with Axon framework, but I would imagine the concepts would still remain the same. Check out this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/domain-events-design-implementation it would give you a good idea of microservices, domain events, and integration events.